# Problem with getting javascript to forget a variables value

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

I'm trying to solve a coding challenge
it gives me an array and waits for the answer ,then gives me the next array and so on.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5648b12ce68d9daa6b000099/train/javascript

I am trying to take this input:  var busStops = [[10,0],[3,5],[5,8]]  and return 5.
the code is supposed to add the first in each pair to a total while subtracting the second in each pair from the total eg: 10 - 0 + 3 - 5 + 5 - 8 = 5

First my code loops through the inner arrays and outer array ,pushing it into myarr as a regular array eg: [10,0,3,5,5,8].

It then adds the value if it is index is 0 or even and subtracts it if the index is odd.
This actually works!
Until it is given a second array eg: [[3,0],[9,1],[4,10],[12,2],[6,1],[7,10]]

It is still calculating the total correctly but is still remembering the total from the first array meaning it is returning 22 instead of 17

Why?
There is a var answer = 0 that is being executed ahead of the second loop
It should forget the value of the previous answer.
Right?

**Edit: I figured out my problem. I just needed to empty myarr after the total was calculated!**

```js
let myarr = [];
var number = function (busStops) {
  for (var i = 0; i < busStops.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < busStops[i].length; j++) {
      /*console.log(busStops[i][j]);*/
      myarr.push(busStops[i][j]);
    }
  }
console.log("test");
var answer = 0;
  console.log("test again");
  for (let t = 0; t < myarr.length; t++) {
    if (t == 0 || t % 2 == 0) {
      answer = answer + myarr[t];
    } else {
      answer = answer - myarr[t];
    }
  }
  console.log(answer);
  return answer;
};
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? "Until it is given a second array" - what does that mean? The given code does not call `number` at all

Comment: You're saving into `myarr` which is shared between all function calls.

Comment: Aside from the above, your code is also falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- you never declare `t`, so when you first assign to it (the `t = 0` in the `for`), you're creating a **global** variable called `t`. Always use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), in which assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been.

Comment: Sorry about not declaring t , fixed it now .

Comment: Added more info to the question for better clarity. Sorry about that ,first question I have ever asked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task at your hand tries to *somehow* find a value (an integer) from an array of arrays (multidimensional array). That task seems to be *reducing* that multidimensional array into a single integer.

Luckily, `JavaScript` has some powerful [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and one of them is the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

> The `reduce()` method executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value. <sup>Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)</sup>

The `reduce` method tries to `reduce` an array's elements into a single value and in your case we want to reduce that multidimensional array into a single value that is *the number persons who are still in the bus*.

Before typing some code, let's dig a bit deeper into the `reduce` method:

- It accepts **2** parameters, a callback function that acts as the *reducer* and the *initial value* to be used in the first iteration of the `reduce` method.
- The *reducer* callback function, on its own, accepts **4** parameters that are supplied by the `reduce` method. You may learn more about those parameters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) as am only going to focus on the first **2** parameters the *reducer* accepts:

  - `previousValue`: hold the value from the previous *reducer* call. On first call, it contains the value you set to the `initial value` parameter of the `reduce` method or, if you didn't supply an initial value, `previousValue` shall hold the value of your array's first element (`arr[0]`).
  - `currentValue`: hold the current `reduce` iteration's item.

Now, let's get back to the task we have, we need to calculate the number of persons who are still in the bus based on a supplied multidimensional array. Each item in that multidimensional array is an array of two values where the result we need at the end is: the sum of the differences between each array, in the multidimensional array, first and second values (`sum = multiDim[i][0] - multiDim[i][1] + multiDim[i + 1][0] + multiDim[i + 1][1]` etc...).

To solve this task, we'll `reduce` that multidimensional array into a single number (let's call it `result`) by using a simple *reducer* function that will start by an initial value of `0` (as we're calculating a sum in our case) and will add, to the `result`, the difference between the first and the second values of the array supplied by the `reduce` at each iteration.

To illustrate, here's a live demo:

```js
/**
* a function that calculates and returns the number of person who are still in the bus or precisely, the sum of the differences between "c[0]" and "c[1]"
* busArray: the supplied multidimensional array to reduce
* the reducer accepts two parameters:
*    r: the result from the last call to the reducer function (initially set to 0, the initial value (see second parameter passed to the "reduce" method))
     c: hold the current iteration's array.
*/
const calculateWhoAreInTheBus = busArray => busArray.reduce((r, c) => r += c[0] - c[1], 0);

/** test the created "calculateWhoAreInTheBus" function */
console.log(calculateWhoAreInTheBus([
  [10, 0],
  [3, 5],
  [5, 8]
])); // should print: 5

console.log(calculateWhoAreInTheBus([
  [3, 0],
  [9, 1],
  [4, 10],
  [12, 2],
  [6, 1],
  [7, 10]
])); // should print: 17

console.log(calculateWhoAreInTheBus([
  [3, 0],
  [9, 1],
  [4, 8],
  [12, 2],
  [6, 1],
  [7, 8]
])); // should print: 21

console.log(calculateWhoAreInTheBus([
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0]
])); // should print: 0
```

Answer (score -2):

I would advice you to use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead. For example like this:

```
const reducer = (previous, current) => previous + current[0] - current[1];
const answer = busStops.reduce(reducer, 0);
```

It is very brief (although this is not a goal in and of itself) and the reducer function does almost trivial work, so it does not complicate unneccesarily. Best of all it encapsulates the functionality with a minimal need of extra variables.

Othwerwise you could simplify your function a bit but use the `let` keyword to keep variables locked to scope like:

```js
function number(busStops) {
    let answer = 0;
    for (let bs of busStops) {
        answer += bs[0] - bs[1];
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: While this code is the far better approach, it doesn't educate the OP as to what the problem is with their original, nor does it tell them *why* this approach is better.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Separately: `reduce` with an off-the-cuff inline function is generally not a good idea. `reduce` is fine in its place: functional programming with predefined, reusable, tested reducer functions. Outside that place, it's just an overcomplicated loop -- easy to get wrong, hard to read. But as Rory said, the main issues here is that there is no explanation of what's wrong with the OP's code, and no explanation of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This is a nearly trivial reducer function that solves the problem without multiple for loops or introduction of new variables in the global scope.

Comment: "I would advice you" - why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase and others - admittedly, I wrote the answer a bit hastely but I stand by it and will try to improve the explanation.

Comment: Thanks that works.   I made that much harder than it needed to be. I have now realized that if I just empty the array after the total is calculated my trainwreck of a piece of code works properly!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept it as an answer. Emptying definitely works too, but the idea is you do not really need to maintain a seperate array.